# Adjective for "of the Tractatus"

Tags: adjectives, convention

Ludwig Wittgenstein's *Tractatus Logico-Philosophicus* introduces a way to constrain language, and I'd like to take an approach inspired by the concepts defined in that work.

What is the correct way to label such an approach? Are there best-practice guidelines for creating adjectives from nouns? These are some that seem legit:

- a Tractatian approach
- a tractatian approach
- a Tractalian approach
- a Tractatusian approach
- a Tractacus approach
- a [TLP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tractatus_Logico-Philosophicus) approach

Comment: Unless you can find find evidence of such usage elsewhere, you would commonly write a construction like *a Tractatus-inspired approach* rather than just making up your own word. (Incidentally, none of your suggestions look legitimate to me.)

Comment: Further to Jason's Comment, even if English was Latin how would it not be clear that Tractatus was the least part of that title?

Your Question seems to suggest Book about Logico-Philosophicus should lead to Bookian… approach, etc. That Tractatus Theologico‑Politicus and Tractatus de Intellectus Emendatione were the only other examples Google threw at me doesn't change that.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Even to someone who doesn't speak Latin, how would it not be clear that Logico-Philosophicus is a qualifier of the noun Tractatus? One refers by using the noun, not its adjectives.

Comment: @JasonBassford You are right, and the commonly used approach is to use TLP as a noun. I will consider my question as ill-posed in the absence of further evidence.

Comment: MrMartin, in no language is Logico-Philosophicus a qualifier. You might get away with insisting the three words together formed a compound noun but that's the only real point.

When speaking of Book of Subject in any language, how could "Book" be the point?

To me it seems asking about “of the Tractatus… ” is either asking about the title of the work - which is not "Tractatus" - or its meaningless.

How could an adjective for “of the Tractatus” as opposed to one for "of the Tractatus Logico-Philosophicus" have any use outside theoretical grammar with no application?